# DataTables persist button content after page reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, local-storage, session-storage

Using datatables and jquery, I am creating a button element in the last column of the table and on a click event changing its text from 'Click' to 'View'. (https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/null_data_source.html)

This works absolute fine but when I reload or terminate the browser, button text goes back to original - 'Click'. Obviously the default content of input element button will be rendered as indicated in 'columnDefs'. How can we persist the button text using local storage/server side rendering (PHP) or how to display some buttons with text 'Click' & others with 'View'?

Experts need your inputs pls!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
      "ajax": {
          "type": "get",
          "url": "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos",            
          "dataType": "json",
          "dataSrc": function (json) {
                 var return_data = new Array();
                 for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
                     return_data.push({
                         'userId': json[i].userId,
                         'id': json[i].id,
                         'title': "Test Data"
                     })
                 }
                 return return_data;
          }
      },
      "columns": [
             { 'data': 'userId' },             
             { 'data': 'id' },
             { 'data': 'title' },
             { 'data': null }
        ],
       "columnDefs": [
         { targets: 0, width: "150px", className: 'dt-body-center'},
         { targets: 1, width: "150px", className: 'dt-body-center'},
         { targets: 2, width: "150px", className: 'dt-body-center'},
         { targets: -1, width: "150px", 
           className: 'dt-body-center', defaultContent:         
           "<button id='btnDetails'>Click</buttom>" }
        ]});

  $('#example tbody').on('click', '[id*=btnDetails]', function () {
       $(this).text("View");
  });  
});
```

```html
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>        
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>
  <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.3/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.3/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
<table id="example" class="display cell-border compact stripe" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>User Id</th>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Title</th> 
                <th>Status</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you add more code or link to codepen to replicate the issue? Yesterday I answered very similar problem but I need edit the code on codepen.

Comment: Are you sure this even works? All your buttons have the same ID so your Javascript click handler will locate the first one and ignore the rest. Instead use a class to trigger the click handler and add a `data-id` attribute if you later need to identify the individual button.

Comment: Localstorage doesn't return a pure boolean value, it might be returning `true` as a string, so if you have any other value set as string then it will be a boolean `true`

Comment: @Tadas- I've added link to code snippet in which I'm trying to change btn text from 'Click' to 'View' once it is clicked. So, at page reload we don't want all the buttons displaying same text - 'Click'.